# AJAX request not working with routing C#

Tags: c#, ajax, routes

I have included the below in my ajax request:

```
$(function () {
$("#DropDownList1").change(function () {
    alert($("#DropDownList1")[0].value);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/bikesearch.aspx/GetModels") %>',
        data: '{id: "' + $("#DropDownList1")[0].value + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (r) {
            var ddlCustomers = $("[id*=DropDownList2]");
            ddlCustomers.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
            $.each(r.d, function () {
                ddlCustomers.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

});

the following is what a portion of my Global.asax file looks like:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("", "bikesearch/{Manufacturer}", "~/bikesearch.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("", "bikesearch/{Manufacturer}/{Model}", "~/bikesearch.aspx");
}
```

the below is what my WebMethod returns:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<ListItem> GetModels(int id)
{
    connection conn = new connection();

    string query = "SELECT Id, Model FROM Model where Manufacturer_Id = " + id;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn.GetConnectionString()))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            List<ListItem> customers = new List<ListItem>();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    customers.Add(new ListItem
                    {
                        Value = sdr["Id"].ToString(),
                        Text = sdr["Model"].ToString()
                    });
                }
            }
            con.Close();
            return customers;
        }
    }
}
```

When trying to fire an AJAX request on the bikesearch.aspx page, the request fails. What could I be doing wrong? any help appreciated.

I have noticed that the below webmethod works fine when returning just a string:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string ebulten_Add()
{
    return "test";
}
```

Comment: please open bikesearch.aspx in google chrome and while Ajax request capture network tab of developper tools(filter xhr in network tab)

Comment: I've never used this before, I got a status 400 bad request message.

Comment: the webmethod that returns the string works fine but the webmethod that returns the list fails, why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Aha, your last comment helped me, you have to serialize your object to `Json` if you want to pass it to Ajax request:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Converters.Add(new ListCompactionConverter());
settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customers,settings); 
return(result);
```

Comment: thanks Vahid, it worked. The only thing i'm having a problem with now is return (JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customers)) returns only Text and not Value items e.g ["RS125","RS50", ....] and not [{0,"RS125"}, {1,"RS50"},...]. What changes would need to be made to the WebMethod and Ajax scripts for the correct results to be displayed? Ajax keeps coming back with undefined when looping through the results.

Comment: I used the following link to clean up the json result http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/629042/Example-Of-JavaScript-Serializer-And-Json-String-U, I wanted to do this in such a way where I didnt need to import Newtonsoft.JSON package. I used used System.Web.Script.Serialization; JavaScriptSerializer(); along with that link and everything seems to be working perfect. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.